# Proper way to close Stream in PDFParser in PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm parsing a PDF document with pdfbox2.0.3:

```
private PDDocument getPDDocument(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser parser = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser(
            new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(inputStream));

    try {
        parser.parse();
    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
        throw new SecurityException("PDF document is protected.", e);
    }

    COSDocument cospd = parser.getDocument();
    return new PDDocument(cospd);
}
```

Later on I close the document to clean up:

```
pd.close();
```

I realized that this was leaving a temporary file in my folder that was not cleaned up.  After playing around, I realized I had to close the RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream specifically.

```
private PDDocument getPDDocument(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream strm = new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(inputStream);

    try {
        org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser parser = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser(strm);

        try {
            parser.parse();
        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
            throw new SecurityException("PDF document is protected.", e);
        }

        COSDocument cospd = parser.getDocument();
        return new PDDocument(cospd);
    } finally {
        strm.close();
    }
}
```

I sort of expected PDDocument, or COSDocument to close this stream for me.  Am I doing something wrong or is this expected?  My code seems to work but I'm not sure if this is the "right time" to close the stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to work with PDFBox 2.* is this:

```
private PDDocument getPDDocument(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
{
    return PDDocument.load(inputStream);
}
```

The correct way to close a document is

```
doc.close();
```

with doc being a PDDocument object.

The current version is 2.0.8.

Another good work pattern is to close the document in the same method where you open it, so you can use try-with-resources of JDK7.

If your InputStream is from a file, then you can and should pass the File object to `open()`, you'll get better performance.

Comment: That works great thanks.  Now I'm wondering why I ever used PDFParser in the first place....

Comment: You're either a longtime user (it was that way many years ago), or you used an outdated tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
   COSDocument cospd = parser.getDocument();
   return new PDDocument(cospd);
```

Try doing this:

```
return parser.getPDDocument();
```